# Magento Setup on AWS server getting Error

Tags: magento2

I am setting up the Magento on AWS server. I have changed the url from
 db as well as from `env` file.

But I am getting following error while installing

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in
>   /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128

```
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(128): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=18.2...', 'root', 'Welcome@1', Array) #1 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #2 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(398): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #3 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect() #4 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #5 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(517): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #6 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(580): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #7 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #8 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/Db/FetchStrategy/Query.php(21): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #9 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(774): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #10 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(670): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select)) #11 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(574): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->getData() #12 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(559): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false) #13 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(831): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load() #14 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(82): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator() #15 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(62): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig() #16 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') #17 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(60): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get() #18 /var/www/html/beta/generated/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() #19 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(292): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #20 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(191): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->readData() #21 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(152): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default') #22 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(131): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...') #23 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(80): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...') #24 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(93): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL) #25 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/HeaderProvider/Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...') #26 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply() #27 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor)) #28 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() #29 /var/www/html/beta/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array) #30 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #31 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(156): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)) #32 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)) #33 /var/www/html/beta/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)) #34 {main} Next Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #1 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(398): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #2 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect() #3 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #4 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(517): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #5 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(580): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #6 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #7 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/Db/FetchStrategy/Query.php(21): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #8 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(774): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #9 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(670): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select)) #10 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(574): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->getData() #11 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(559): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false) #12 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(831): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load() #13 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(82): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator() #14 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(62): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig() #15 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') #16 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(60): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get() #17 /var/www/html/beta/generated/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() #18 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(292): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #19 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(191): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->readData() #20 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(152): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default') #21 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(131): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...') #22 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(80): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...') #23 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(93): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL) #24 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/HeaderProvider/Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...') #25 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply() #26 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor)) #27 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() #28 /var/www/html/beta/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array) #29 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #30 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(156): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)) #31 /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)) #32 /var/www/html/beta/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)) #33 {main}
```

Comment: Have you checked your credential are correct  ?

Comment: Yes my cerdentials are correct. I have checked twice

Comment: These are not errors, they are just saying that the cache has been invalidated. If these are the only messages you are seeing in any log files. You can turn off logging to stop them coming out if they are a problem.

Comment: try to run this to check mysql credential is ok on CLI mode. mysql -h YOUR_HOST -u YOUR_USERNAME -p YOUR_DATABASE

Comment: I think there issue in your database connection. Please check your credential.

Comment: Now getting 

Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in /var/www/html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on lin

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this error?